# How do I fix the substring to use like in SQL code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, substring, sql-like

my declaration:

```
declare @status varchar(255);
set @status = 'seated'
```

This is what my table structure looks like

```
**description**
Seated, Unpaid
Seated, Paid
Return
Seating Failed
Unseated, Paid
Upgraded
Ticketed, Paid
Unseatable
etc.
```

My general code:

```
select  description
from    tr_status
where   description like Substring(@status,0,LEN(status))
```

What I would like to do is say where ever the description field has 'seated' in it (or whatever value is passed as my paramter). return only those lines where seated exists as part of the description.

so only these:

```
Seated, Unpaid
Seated, Paid
Unseated, Paid
```

Comment: All 3 solutions after me are wrong, String concatenation is done with || not with +

Comment: @maraca [That is not true whatsoever.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)

Comment: @MariM I'm sorry, I missread oracle, probably another question. Should I remove my comment? Or leave it there so people know to what you answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  description
FROM    tr_status
WHERE   description LIKE '%' + @status + '%'
```

% in SQL is a wildcard, so will match any series of characters. The LIKE statement allows concatenation of variables alongside this wildcard, resulting in the sort of search you're asking for.

Comment: I know its a wildcard, but I couldn't figure out how to link it to the parameter. I didn't realize simply concatenating it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use substring for that:

```
WHERE description LIKE @status
```

Should do the trick. Or in the worse case:

```
WHERE description LIKE '%' + @status + '%'
```